# Find and Replace string in Android

Tags: android, string, replace

```
myString = "my name=\"ppshein\""
```

How can I remove "**=\"ppshein\"**" from the above string in Android?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can remove strings this way:

```
string.replace("=\"ppshein\"", "");
```

Comment: string.replace("\" with \\\"", "");

Answer (score 2):

```
myString.replace("=\"ppshein\"", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a string called `myString` and you want a new string with all occurrences of `="ppshein"` removed, try

```
String newString = myString.replace("=\"ppshein\"", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the above string won't compile. you need to write it like: `myString = "my name=\"ppshein\""`

Secondly, use: `myString = myString.replace("=\"ppshein\"", "");`

Answer (score 0):

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("StringToReplace", "");
```